# How do you pass variables through nested objects using apply/call for closures

Tags: javascript

I am having problems understanding how call/apply works even after reading through the tutorials on websites and here on SO. I understand the basic mechanics until things become nested. Without relying on that = this, how would I do this using the call function instead for a closure?

```
var createPerson = function () {
    var that = this;
    var name;

    return {
        bio: {
            name: function (name) {
                that.name = name;
            }
        },
        getInfo: {
            getName: function () {
                return that.name;
            }
        }
    }

}

var john = createPerson();
john.bio.name("Johnathan");
console.log(john.getInfo.getName());
```

Comment: Have you looked at `bind`, this will set the context to the passed paramerter, no matter how the function is called, it's context will always the passed context

Comment: I have, but haven't figured it out as well at a advanced level. I was planning on spending a lot of time playing with it after I had a better understanding of apply/call. Would you recommend doing the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is use `this` on your functions and `call` it with the returned object.

```
var createPerson = function () {
    return {
        bio: {
            name: function (name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
        },
        getInfo: {
            getName: function () {
                return this.name;
            }
        }
    }
}
var john = createPerson();
john.bio.name.call(john, 'Jonathan');
console.log(person.getInfo.getName.call(john));
```

`Function.prototype.call` will invoke your function with `john` being `this`.

An example of `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
var createPerson = function () {
    var person = {
        bio: {},
        getInfo: {}
    };
    person.bio.name = Function.bind.call(function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }, person);
    person.getInfo.getName = Function.bind.call(function () {
        return this.name;
    }, person);
    return person;
}

var john = createPerson();
john.bio.name("Johnathan");
console.log(john.getInfo.getName());
```

Notice, that you can just as easily replace it for this:

```
var createPerson = function () {
    var person = {
        bio: {},
        getInfo: {}
    };
    person.bio.name = function (name) {
        person.name = name;
    }
    person.getInfo.getName = function () {
        return person.name;
    }
    return person;
}

var john = createPerson();
john.bio.name("Johnathan");
console.log(john.getInfo.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you show a example that is automated though? For example using call inside the object?

Comment: That would be pointless, you'd still need a closure for `this`, in which case it would be better to just use the closure directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is where I am a bit confused. I don't understand why it would be pointless. Is there a tutorial or something that you know of that goes over this in depth that you can refer me to?

Comment: It would be pointless because `call` invokes the function. When you are creating the object, you don't need to invoke the function, rather pass a subset of functions to which you want to call later on. In that case, you'd need to use `Function.prototype.bind`, as that returns a function with `this` binded to a specific object.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense as you can just as easily use the closure instead of `this`.

Comment: No problem, I'd really recommend you reading the articles of the MDN, especially [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)